# How to unify and manage overloaded functions?

Tags: c#, try-catch, overloading

This code works by taking a function as a parameter and using try-catch to log the result of the function.

When I change the functionDecorator here, I want the changes to be applied automatically to functionDecorator<T> or functionDecorator<T1, T2> without copying the entire code as it is now

These functions that do almost the same thing Is there a way to manage each other's behavior in one place, including even try-catch statements?

```
        public void funtionDecorator(Func<bool> Func, string successText = "success", string failText = "fail", string errorText = "error")
        {
            try
            {
                if (Func())
                {
                    txtStatusBar.Text = successText;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtStatusBar.Text = failText;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                txtStatusBar.Text = errorText + Func.Method.Name + ex.ToString();
            }
        }

        // ex : funtionDecorator<DataTable>(useDataFuntion, dt);
        public void funtionDecorator<T>(Func<T, bool> Func, T type, string successText = "success", string failText = "fail", string errorText = "error")
        {
            try
            {
                if (Func(type))
                {
                    txtStatusBar.Text = successText;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtStatusBar.Text = failText;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                txtStatusBar.Text = errorText + Func.Method.Name + ex.ToString();
            }
        }

        // ex : funtionDecorator<DataTable, Double>(useDataFuntion, dt, value);
        public void funtionDecorator<T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2, bool> Func, T1 type1, T2 type2, string successText = "success", string failText = "fail", string errorText = "error")
        {
            try
            {
                if (Func(type1, type2))
                {
                    txtStatusBar.Text = successText;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtStatusBar.Text = failText;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                txtStatusBar.Text = errorText + Func.Method.Name + ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

I tried to handle it dynamically using dynamic, but the function type was not converted to dynamic, so I couldn't find a way.

Comment: Accept only `Func<T>` and let caller compose call himself. For example, instead of doing `functionDecorator(this.SomeMethod, 1, 2, 3)`, caller will do `functionDecorator(() => this.SomeMethod(1,2,3))`

Comment: @Evk It was an answer that satisfies all my requirements. Thank you very much.
But functionDecorator(() => this.SomeMethod()) not only lambda expression
I don't know why a lambda expression with an input variable like functionDecorator(() => this.SomeMethod(1,2,3)) is recognized as a Func<T> type.
 If it's ok, can you give me some advice?

Comment: lambda expression () => this.SomeMethod(1,2,3) has no input arguments, and returns one value (assuming `SomeMethod` is not void). So it can be converted to delegate of form `T SomeDelegate()` such as `Func<T>`